# IntelliJ coditional breakpoint [JAVA]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

im trying to hit my code based on a particular condition.
For eg :-

```
public  TXN_DATA callExternalServ ( Dummy_class dummy_obj  )    {
    
    log.debug(" Entering function 'callExternalServ'");

    
    ..
    ...
    //      logic
    
}

public class Dummy_class{
    
    int var1;
    String var2;
    
    //      getters & setters
    //      constructors
    
    
}
```

I want to hit `callExternalServ` method only when the input parameter to this method i.e.  Dummy_class's object, has value `x` in its `var1` attribute.

Is anything like this achievable in IDEA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the break point and you can set the condition as you will see the following

[image]